# Hovering over the X to delete a comment created via the android app moves comments below

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app

On chrome, 29.0.1547.57 m.

I've used the android app to create comments, as such they appear as below when hovering over them on the desktop version:

[image]

Hovering over the x does this:

[image]

It's not easy to see in the screenshots, but the comment by Cole Johnson moves down 1 or 2 pixels when I hover over the x.

---

Comments below shouldn't get jiggled when hovering over the x of a comment submitted via the SE android app.

Comment: Jiggling comments! What'll they think of next?

Comment: I don't generally mind jiggling, but needless jiggling seems a waste.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be resolved with a recent refactoring of comments.  If you find it to still be an issue let me know.